# Tensorflow: How to display confusion matrix (tensor) as an array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, confusion-matrix, tensor

I have successfully obtained the confusion matrix of (7x7). It is in tensor form.

I want to view the confusion matrix. Tried .eval and sess method but it doesnt work.

my code:

```
n_classes = 7
prediction = neural_network(x)
correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

con_mat = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], predictions=correct, num_classes=n_classes, dtype=tf.int32, name=None)

print('Confusion Matrix: \n\n', tf.SparseTensor.eval(con_mat, feed_dict=None, session=None))
```

output:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'indices'
```

[tf.SparseTensor.eval](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/sparse_ops/sparse_tensor_representation#SparseTensor.eval)

Neural Network:

```
weights = {
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_units, n_classes], dtype=tf.float32))
    }
    biases = {
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_classes]))
    }

    x = tf.unstack(x, seq_len, 1)

    # 3-layer LSTM with 128 units.
    cell = rnn_cell_impl.MultiRNNCell([rnn_cell_impl.LSTMCell(hidden_units),
                                       rnn_cell_impl.LSTMCell(hidden_units),
                                       rnn_cell_impl.LSTMCell(hidden_units)])

    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']

    return output
```

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: Done editing. @mpf82

Comment: It looks like the indentation is wrong in that code example (and it can be significant, especially if you're using a `with` statement). Also, can you enlarge the example to include where `sess` is created?

Comment: I have found a function from tensorflow to evaluate the confusion matrix, which is a sparse tensor. 

Edited my code and error.

@mrry

Answer (score 6):

You can view the confusion matrix by running

```
con_mat = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], predictions=correct, num_classes=n_classes, dtype=tf.int32, name=None)

with tf.Session():
   print('Confusion Matrix: \n\n', tf.Tensor.eval(con_mat,feed_dict=None, session=None))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but it has this error:

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [-1,100,88] has negative dimensions
  [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,100,88], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Comment: Can you add prediction and n_classes value in your question?

Comment: Done :) I am using 3 layer LSTM  @Bharath Shetty

Comment: I meant the variable `correct` in the form of a matrix or a numpy array. Or the shape of the `correct`.

Comment: the variable correct is a tensor.. not matrix or numpy array. 

**Tensor("Equal:0", shape=(?,), dtype=bool)**

Comment: The problem is in `correct`, predictions parameter should be a one dimensional tensor of known length. Here you have a Tensor with shape (?,), that is a one-dimensional tensor of unknown length.

Comment: I see.. but my variable 'prediction' and 'y' for **correct** has shape of (?,7). is this how it suppose to be? sorry, im new to deep learning. and does the error affect my accuracy too?

Comment: Those should be finite

Comment: weights has the shape of : (128, 7)
biases has the shape of : (7,)
multi rnn cell have the shape of : (?,128)
output from matmul has the shape of: (?,7)

can you tell me which part possibly gone wrong so that i can change accordingly? :)

will post my code for neural network in my question

Answer (score 0):

Defining the confusion matrix (in the context of a neural network, but same method applies to others):

```
confusion = tf.confusion_matrix(tf.argmax(one_hot, 1),tf.argmax(logits, 1))
```

Running and printing the matrix:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    test_confusion = sess.run(confusion, feed_dict={X_place:X,y_place:y})
    print(test_confusion)
```

Comment: what are X_place and y_place?

Comment: @M.Chavoshi It's the dataset to feed in.